# how to save data by loop in redis

Tags: node.js, redis

using this redis node client 
https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

i want to save the three uses simultaneously in loop . 
but not able to save only last users is getting saved ? 
here i want to save rahul0,rahul1, rahul2 to be as users in redis 
but only rahul2 is getting saved.

```js
var redis = require("redis"),
    sys = require("sys"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.del("channels.59-O");

for(var j=0; j<3; j++) {
    client.hgetall("channels.59-O", makeCallback(j));
    function makeCallback(index) {
        return function(err, result){
            console.log('check '+sys.inspect(result));
            if(!result.users) {
                var channeldata={
                    'users':"rahul"+index
                };
                console.log('dsfsdc'+sys.inspect(channeldata));
                client.hmset('channels.59-O', channeldata);
            } else {
                var users=result.users.split(',');
                users.push("rahul"+index);
                var channeldata={
                    'users':users.join(',')
                };
                console.log('check 1 '+sys.inspect(channeldata));
                client.hmset('channels.59-O', channeldata);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing over the same hash key everytime, so the last user `hmset` will prevail over the others.

Change

```
client.hmset('channels.59-O', channeldata)
```

to

```
client.hmset('channels.59-O:' + index, channeldata)
```

With this, every user will have his *own hash key*, identified by a *suffix*.

So, in your example, after this you can access (e.g. via `redis-cli`), `channels.59-O:0` for `rahul0` data, `channels.59-O:1` for `rahul1` data etc.

Also, you will have to manage their deletions, `client.del("channels.59-O")` will have to be now `client.del("channels.59-O:0")`, `client.del("channels.59-O:1")` etc.

Hope that helps. Also check this similar answer: [Writing a query to add multiple values to a key in REDIS Hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864968/writing-a-query-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-key-in-redis-hashes/6876888#6876888)

Comment: thanks for answer , i inserted all users in a one go to redis not by loop, if you think i done it right way the please update your answer

Comment: If you keep updating the *same key*, without the suffix, it will keep retaining only the last save, therefore the last user. The important point is the *key*. You can't save all users in the `channels.59-O` key, you must specify a new key (with suffix) for each of them.

Comment: i don't want to give  the key

Comment: I don't understand, please update the question and put your most recent code. Thanks.

Comment: Run your program then run `redis-cli`, then `keys *`. This will list all keys in the database. You will see then what happened inside Redis.